# How to edit an html file and add tags to it at specific positions using javascript and nodejs?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have an html file stored in a variable "html" in my javascript program.

```
html = "<html>
         <body>
          <p id="p1"> Hello </p>
         </body>
        </html> "
```

This is the value of html variable and the value is coming from a database query.

Now I have to add a tag after the p1 tag in my html file like

```
tag = "<p id="p2"> World</p>".
```

How can I edit this html file and add p2 tag after the p1 tag? I am using a node environment.

Comment: Do you want the output to be `html = \`<html>
<body>
 <p id="p1">
  Hello
 </p>
 <p id="p2">
  World
 </p>
</body>
</html>\``

Comment: @Vinayak yes I want the output to be like that

Answer (score 0):

> We will be separating our webpage into 3 variables
>
>  
>  And you can separate them further as per your need

You can separate them in different variables like

`html1 = "<html><body>";` --> The starting of the webpage

`html2 ="</body> </html>";` --> The ending of the webpage

`bodyPart = "<p id="p1"> Hello </p>";` --> Matter Inside body

**Then you can simply do `bodyPart+=tag`**

And then you can make a html like

`html = html1+bodyPart+html2;`

Comment: how to get html1 here

Comment: What do you Mean? can you explain please

Comment: "html = html1+bodyPart+html2". What would be "html1" here?

Comment: <html><body> ---> Starter Template